# div with margins & padding that needs to fill its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a container div (it has both width an height set in pixels).

Is there a way to add a child div that will fill its entire parent but still have margin and or padding ?

suppose the parent div is 200px wide, and 200px high.

if I give the child div a width/height of 100% then it assumes that I mean for the content are to be of size 200px and then if I add padding or margins the size of the child becomes bigger then that of the parent.

I want the child div's content area to be what ever is left after taking out 5px margins on each side...

and **please don't tell me to subtract 2*5px from 200px**  - I know that but I am looking for a better solution.

could it be that css can't handle such a simple task...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wYNYh/1/

Comment: I like this solution (even though I have to add the 5px 4 times) because 1) is does what I asked. 2) it does not modify the container element. Thanks. If not better solution will show itself I will accept this answer.

Comment: what would you do with respect to the absolute/ralative positions if you wanted an #insideInner div that will relate to #inner in the same way that #inner relates to #outer?

Comment: You could use the same css again. Just change #inner to .inner so you can reuse it as a class. It should work for for nested divs aswell.

Answer (score 3):

Set all elements to have box-sizing as border-box in your stylesheet.

This will sum up the padding of all elements so you don't have to worry about any disruptions if you add any padding.

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; this is literally the intention of the box-sizing property.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rnf82/ ?

Comment: see the coment posted on Dennis Traub's suggested answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the padding of the outer div. Then the inner div will only occupy what's left.

Have a look at this: ([try yourself at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFT74/))

```
.outer {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #DD0000;
 padding: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;   
 background-color: #0000DD;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

really these two ways of doing this is equivalent as far as the question is concerned. It is important to remember the redundancy generated by how `html` and `css` standards are setup.

Comment: this will make the `.outer` 210px wide and high. Correcting this by changing 200 to 190 is essentially the same as: *... and please don't tell me to subtrach 2*5px from 200px ...*